# Group query in Grafana GQL to use a field from another query as legend

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, grafana, monitoring

I'm trying to monitor the bandwidth usage of each node of my Kubernetes cluster but I cannot find a way to use the node name as legend.

To get the bandwidth input, I use the query:

```
sum by(instance) (irate(node_network_receive_bytes_total[$interval:$resolution]))
```

*Note: interval and resolution are time based value (e.g, 4h:30s)*

But this returns me the instance by their IP address and `node_network_receive_bytes_total` has no `nodename` field.

So I want to use the query

```
node_uname_info
```

To get the node name and then combine these field to use the `node_name` as legend for corresponding instance.

I tried to use transform `join by labels` and multiple techniques to find a solutions but I couldn't find one.

Is it actually possible with Grafana? If so, how can I do that because I always ends up with IP address as legend and couldn't find a way to merge these fields with a GQL query.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query to group by nodename but based on instance label.

```
sum by (instance)(irate(node_network_receive_bytes_total[4h:30s])) * on(instance) group_left(nodename) (node_uname_info)
```

Hope this helps.